# How to listen for firebase link confirmation event to mail from react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In general, I connected firebase to the application, set up sending a letter with an email confirmation, but I still didn't understand how to listen to the click on the link (((
Who is in the subject? - I would be grateful!

```
const testMail = 'myMail@gmail.com'

const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: "https://myApp.page.link/__/auth/verify",
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOS: {
      bundleId: "myApp.firebase.ios"
    },
    android: {
      packageName: "myApp.firebase.android",
      installApp: true,
      minimumVersion: "16"
    }
}

firebase
    .auth()
    .sendSignInLinkToEmail(testMail, actionCodeSettings)
    .then( () => {
      ....
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for changes in the users auth state (logging in and out).
This method returns a unsubscribe function to stop listening to events.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: My app sent message to user's email and wait for answer. User hasn't logged in yet. Probably I should use "isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)", but how I can know the value of emailLink?

Comment: When I put the code I gave above to app.js, when the user clicks on the link in the mail, you will catch it because the firebase authorization status will change.